# How to scroll TFlowLayout content vertically?

Tags: delphi, layout, firemonkey, flowlayout

I have a TFlowLayout containing 5 same-sized controls. The TFlowLayout (with Align=Top) is a child of TVertScrollBox. When making the flowlayout smaller all 5 controls are displayed as one column. This works fine. However, when these 5 controls don't fit within the view then I would expect TVertScrollBox to kick in and provide the vertical scrolling capability.
It turns out that the TFlowLayout.Height property is not adjusted to a new height that corresponds with the height of the 5 controls displayed in that one column. 
What would be the best way to provide vertical scrolling in this case?

Comment: Solved! I inherited a TMyFlowLayout from TControl (copy of TFlowLayout) and added "Height := CurPos.Y + LineHeight" as last line to DoRealign. Works like a charm! I'll register as feature request at EMB